# Use of css in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, css, visual-studio-2010

I have a doubt that in asp.net I am using CssClass class attribute for web server controls. And i am writing all the css code in style.css which will be in style folder of my project

```
    <asp:TextBox ID="UserName" runat="server" CssClass="textEntry"></asp:TextBox>
```

The above is the example of the textbox.

Now the question is do i need to use link tag to say that my css file is located in style folder of my project?

Comment: You simply need to include your stylesheet in your HTML with the `<style>` or `<link>` tag.

Answer (score 4):

Yes, you have to link the style sheet file (.css) by adding the `link` tag.

You can also simply drag the css file into the html section of the .aspx code right under `head` tag, that will work too - that will create the link for you.

[image: See the image below]

Comment: you mean just by dragging and dropping the style folder into my aspx file. It will work?

Comment: No, not the folder - you have to drag the css file.

Comment: Glad to help. Don't forget to accept the answer that worked for you!

Answer (score 1):

Of course you need to link to your css file just like you do in regular html:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style/mystyle.css">
```

While writing `.aspx` file just think as if you are writing an HTML file with the ability to pre-process the page through the ASP.NET view engine (which is where the additional `asp` tags come into play).

Comment: If he is using themes (correctly) then the <link> element will be added automatically.

Answer (score 0):

No, the tag is only used to apply a class within your CSS file. Just make sure you link your CSS file with your page as follows:

```
<head>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="path_to_your.css">
</head>
```